# What is SpringBoot's session scope?Why won't this work?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have SpringBoot application code like this:

```java
    class HelloMessageGenerator{
        public static int num = 0;
        public HelloMessageGenerator(){
            System.out.println("new session");
        }

        public void doSomething(){
            System.out.println("doSomething");
        }
    }

    @Controller
    class ScopesController {
        @Resource(name = "sessionScopedBean")
        HelloMessageGenerator sessionScopedBean;

        @Bean
        @SessionScope
        public HelloMessageGenerator sessionScopedBean() {
            return new HelloMessageGenerator();
        }

        @RequestMapping("/")
        public String getSessionScopeMessage(final Model model) {
            sessionScopedBean.doSomething();
            return "hello";
        }
    }

    @SpringBootApplication
    public class DemoApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        }

    }
```

And i've set `server.sessionTimeout=1`.

But when i refresh the browser page, it doesn't process the constructer of `HelloMessageGenerator`,

the output is like that:

[image]

I thought the output should be:

**new session**

**doSomething**

**new session**

**doSomething**

**new session**

**doSomething**

Comment: Have you tried in an "incognito" browser session?

Comment: I work on incognito browser session,but why won't it work on normal one.I've set the timeout to be 1.Shouldn't it be work like i expected?

Comment: I think it's server.session.timeout, not server.sessionTimeout

Comment: I try server.session.timeout too,nothing changed

Comment: From the docs: 

If we configured our project to use Tomcat, we have to keep in mind that it only supports minute precision for session timeout, with a minimum of one minute. This means that if we specify a timeout value of 170s for example, it will result in a 2 minutes timeout.

Maybe wait a bit longer?

Comment: and several mins pass,it still the same...i just don't know why